# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor') How can I handle this error correctly

Tags: node.js, session, mysql2, node-mysql2, telegraf.js

please help.

I'm making use of the node mysql2 and telegraf-mysql-session to  store sessions and execute queries in my telegram bot.

I have SQL queries and whenever a query is run and some variables are null in that query it triggers this error. This is usually when the session variables are null. AgentID=Null or DealerID=Null.

**The error originates from the mysql2 connection.js file**

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pavstockallocatebot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:538
    if (sql.constructor === Commands.Query) {
            ^
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')
```

**Where it is triggered:**

```
query(sql, values, cb) {
    let cmdQuery;
    if (sql.constructor === Commands.Query) {
      cmdQuery = sql;
    } else {
      cmdQuery = Connection.createQuery(sql, values, cb, this.config);
    }
    this._resolveNamedPlaceholders(cmdQuery);
    const rawSql = this.format(cmdQuery.sql, cmdQuery.values !== undefined ? cmdQuery.values : []);
    cmdQuery.sql = rawSql;
    return this.addCommand(cmdQuery);
  }
```

**The code area where the constructor is undefined, It's from telegraf-mysql-session**

```
class MySQLSession {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = Object.assign(
      {
        property: "session",
        getSessionKey: (ctx) => {
          if (ctx.updateType === "callback_query") {
            ctx = ctx.update.callback_query.message;
          }
          if (!ctx.from || !ctx.chat) {
            return;
          }
          return `${ctx.chat.id}:${ctx.chat.id}`;
        },
        store: {},
      },
      options
    );
```

It freezes my telegram bot and the bot can't restart without displaying this error in fact it keeps trying to redo the code section that triggered the error.

How can I add an error handler that will check if the variables are undefined or null to avoid ever getting this error and when I do get this error to handle it appropriately.

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the `query` method?